# Make a Youtube video a full height and width cover video

Tags: html, css, youtube

I want to use a Youtube video as a fullscreen background for a splash page (including sound). However there should be no controls, ability to pause, etc. It should just look like a background movie.

What is the best way to do this?

Should I be using the  tag or is there some other HTML5 tag, or entirely different method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok to use JS/jQuery: http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/

Also, see the source if you want to take some of the concepts: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use YT player, I recommend you to use [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Please keep in mind that you can make the player full-background size, but you can't stretch the video inside the player (so you will need to accept black stripes for different screen ratio than original ratio of the video). I recommend you to use html5 video player (maybe [video.js](http://www.videojs.com) can help you)

P.S.: @Besto's suggestion Tubular breaks Youtube's Terms of Services!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ytcon" style="overflow: hidden">
<iframe id="fullyt" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QVr0M7WCBu4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$("#ytcon").height($(window).height());
$("#ytcon").width($(window).width());
$("#fullyt").height($(window).height());
$("#fullyt").width($(window).width());

$(window).on('resize', function(){
$("#ytcon").height($(window).height());
$("#ytcon").width($(window).width());
$("#fullyt").height($(window).height());
$("#fullyt").width($(window).width());
});

</script>
```

Comment: And if you want to hide the bars on top and bottom of the video, you can remove the top by styling #fullyt top a negative top margin, and then making it the necessary number of pixels larger than the window.